# Reading BLOB data which is stored as Binary datatype in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

We have Oracle BLOB and VARBINARY (SQL Server/Progress) data in hive which is stored as String or Binary datatype. We have brought data from respective RDBMS using sqoop. Now that we have data in hdfs, we like to see the actual attachments like pdf , images, doc etc.. How can we deserialize the hive binary format data to corresponding files?

In short we need to convert binary data in hive to corresponding attachments (pdf,jpg,doc) assuming we know the file type.

Comment: IMHO, what you have in source -- i.e. storing "attachments" in a RDBMS as a kind of makeshift file system -- is plain stupid. But RDBMS vendors like stupid ideas because it often results in additional licensing costs, so they make efforts to grab extra money. Now, trying to replicate that lame design in an Open Source system that was **not** designed for that is... not a good idea. My guess is that you will have to develop your own "viewer" from scratch.

Comment: BTW, you don't mention the Serde you intend to use with Hive. And you don't mention what kind of access pattern and what performance you want (e.g. can you accept random reads taking more than 3 min each?)

Comment: Thanks Samson... I was looking into any possible ways of viewing those attachments once they are in hdfs. So not worried serde , performance etc for the time being.tried to connect via hive jdbc and write file using output stream, in java , still not able to open the output file.Any such ideas?

Comment: **If** the binary content was transferred as-is to Hive `BINARY`, then you should be able to retrieve it as-is via JDBC, in a Java `byte[]` -- and at this point it's your problem to find a viewer. On the other hand, if you used a Hive `STRING` (with implicit UTF-8 encoding -- any non-compliant code will be trashed) and get it into a Java `String` (using some internal encoding such as UTF-16 w/ automatic conversion from UTF-8, adding `null` bytes for padding) then you are doomed.

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking for same solution. please update me if you found any thing..thanks.